# Vector subscript out of range error, C++, bubble sort

Tags: c++, stdvector

I need to do a simple bubble sort in C++ and i want to learn how to use std::vector. But when i run this programm i got this error...

I don't understand why... because i don't think my iteration go out of the range.

Any idea ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void triABulle(vector<int>&, int, int);
void echanger(vector<int>&, int, int);
void affiche(vector<int>&);

int main() {

vector<int> tab = { 3, 4, 56, 3, 2, 5, 64, 3453, 34 };
affiche(tab);
triABulle(tab, 0, tab.size());
cin.get();
return 0;
}

void triABulle(vector<int>& tab, int begin, int end) {

for (size_t i = 1; i <= end-begin; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = end; j >= begin+i; j--)
    {
        if (tab[j] < tab[j-1])
        {
            echanger(tab, j, j-1);
            cout << "SWAP!" << endl;
            affiche(tab);
        }
    }
  }
}

void echanger(vector<int>& tab, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = tab[i];
    tab[i] = tab[j];
    tab[j] = tmp;
}

void affiche(vector<int>& tab) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < tab.size() ; i++)
   {
        cout << tab[i] << ' ';
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `i <= end-begin` if there are `end - begin` elements in the array, they are indexed by 0, so `tab[end-begin]` is one element beyond the end of the vector. E.g. if `end-begin` is 1, then `tab[0]` is the only element in the array. But because you're using `<=` you will try to access `tab[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ array indexes go from 0 to length-1, not 1 to length.

The technique of half open intervals is useful.

```
for (int i = 0; i < end-begin; i++)
{
  for (int j = end-1; j >= begin+i; j--)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that C++ is 0-indexed, meaning indicies start at 0. This implies that if we declare

```
vector<int> tab = { 3, 4, 56, 3, 2, 5, 64, 3453, 34 };
```

then the access

```
tab[tab.size()]
```

will be out of bounds. Observe that you also call

```
triABulle(tab, 0, tab.size()); // so tab.size() == end
```

and have an inner loop of

```
for (size_t j = end; j >= begin+i; j--) {
    if (tab[j] < tab[j-1]) // results in going out of bounds
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

your if statement will be out of bounds since `end == tab.size()`. This access is why you get the subscript out of range error.